# How to reload a custom NSTableRowView in NSOutlineView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to modify the appearance of a custom NSTableRowView used in my NSOutlineView when the row expands/collapses. My NSOutlineViewDelegate includes:

```
- (NSTableRowView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView rowViewForItem:(id)item
{
    ...
    return rowView;
}

- (void)itemDidExpand:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    id item = [userInfo objectForKey:@"NSObject"];
    NSOutlineView *outlineView = [notification object];
    [outlineView reloadItem:item];
}
```

This unfortunately doesn't reload the custom row view.

Reloading data for the entire NSOutlineView works:

```
- (void)itemDidExpand:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [outlineView reloadData];
}
```

But with large amounts of data this can be time consuming, and often leads to a spinning beach ball.

Is it possible to reload the custom row view for just a single top-level item?

Comment: Are you trying to modify color or something?

Comment: Yes, the custom table row view overrides drawSeparatorInRect: and drawBackgroundInRect: to change the colours depending on whether the item is expanded or collapsed.

Comment: i put a solution below. let me know if it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following method:

```
-(void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView didAddRowView:(NSTableRowView *)rowView forRow:(NSInteger)row {
    aColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:(r/255.0f) green:(g/255.0f) blue:(b/255.0f) alpha:1.0];
    [view setBackgroundColor:aColor];
}
```

You can advance this further to get the row object, and then determine which color you want for a particular row.

-**Edit**-

If you wish to alter the parent cell view to show that it has been expanded you have implemented the wrong method for the NSOutlineview. Implement the method like the following:

```
-(void)outlineViewItemWillExpand:(NSNotification *)notification {
    id theObject = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSObject"];

    NSInteger row = [theOutlineView rowForItem:theObject];
    NSTableRowView *theRowView = [theOutlineView rowViewAtRow:row makeIfNecessary:NO];

    int r = 110;
    int g = 110;
    int b = 110;

    NSColor *aColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:(r/255.0f) green:(g/255.0f) blue:(b/255.0f) alpha:1.0];
    [theRowView setBackgroundColor:aColor];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jai, I tried this but unfortunately outlineView:didAddRowView:forRow: is only called on the child rows, not the row that's being expanded/collapsed.

Comment: im confused (1) Isnt the rows thats being expanded/collapsed child rows? (2) this is called when ANY row is added. can you provide some code?

Comment: The parent row contains the disclosure triangle - when it's clicked, it expands and the child rows are shown. At that time I want to change the background colour of the parent row to indicate that it has been expanded. Unfortunately however the only way I've been able to achieve this so far is to call reloadData on the entire NSOutlineView. I'm searching for a way to force only the parent row's custom rowView to redraw itself, without reloading the whole table.

Comment: Outstanding thank you @Jai! Calling rowViewAtRow:makeIfNecessary from outlineViewWillExpand was exactly what was required.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your rowViewForItem method.
It reloads and redisplays the data for item.

```
    - (void)reloadItem:(id)item;
```

Comment: rowViewForItem isn't being called again for this row - that's what I want to be able to trigger. I'm calling reloadItem from itemDidExpand, and it is reloading the row views for child rows, but not for the row being expanded which needs to change appearance.